# How to share data among multiple tenant of different server in a SaaS product?

Tags: database, multi-tenant

I am developing a SaaS product where we have two shared database for multiple tenants (10-20). Now we want that one tenant will be able to share its some data with another tenant in different server. For example, we have a 'book' table in server#1 where tenant 1's data is kept along with few other tenants (like 3,4,5). In another server, we have tenant2's data in a similar fashion. Now, how can i share some rows of Book Table of tenant1 (server1) to tenant2 (server2). If these two tenants were in same server, i could make new relational table to keep this sharing information. Now What are the possible solutions for this problem ?

I am new in this type of multi tenant structure, i don't even know what is a good keyword to search in google to learn these stuffs.

I was hoping to find how google and slack allows for multi-tenant using domain extension like xyz.slack.com. Any suggestion on where I can get more information on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the architecture of your application, like how do you resolve the connectionstrings for the books when requested from tenant 1 and tenant 2.

However, what you can do is have a separate table that has the following structure

```
reference id : tenant ids       : access rights    : isvalid
book1        : tenant1, tenant2 : view_sharedbooks : true
```

(OR)

```
reference id : tenantid : userid      : access rights    : isvalid
book1        : tenant1  : u1          : view_sharedbooks : true
book1        : tenant2  : u2          : view_sharedbooks : true
```

So, When i Login as a user in tenant1, i will be able to look in to the corresponding books that i have access to and their tenant's. When i know the tenant's, i will be able to do a look up for getting their corresponding connectionstring. Using that i will be able to invoke 2 async calls to fetch the db records in 2 database and merge them in the service layer and pass it on to the presentation tier.

This assumes that you have already taken care of the necessary infrastructure that can handle the connections / tenant and also the user and the privileges against the book entity etc...

HTH.